# Access Control to Seatwaves API

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using seatwaves api and have run into an error, The issue is that when i load hte table that the json is on i run into this error in the console `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

i'm still quite new to this so any help or all the help would be so greateful!

Thanks
Sam

Heres the ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'api link for seatwave',
    success: function(json) {
        //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.results.TicketGroups.length; i++) {
            var section = json.results.TicketGroups[i].TicketTypeName;
            var no = json.results.TicketGroups[i].Qty;
            var price = json.results.TicketGroups[i].
            Price;
            var button =
                "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Click Here</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>seatwave</td><td>" + section +
                "</td><td>N/A</td><td>N/A</td><td>" + no +
                "</td><td>£"+price +
                "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
        sortTable();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Browser does not allow cross domain AJAX requests due to security issues. Cross-domain requests are allowed only if the server specifies same origin security policy. If you have access to the server code then it is possible. Check out this post http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/

Comment: Hi there, I've breifly looked over this but got confused, will have to have another look again. Thanks